# Как настроить интернет в LinuxMint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, модемы

Установил LinuxMint 16 Petra MATE (х32). Ось супер, но уже две недели мучаюсь - не могу подключить интернет "Мегалайн". Облазил кучу форумов, но ответы везде только для кабельного инета, а у меня модем (через телефон). Модем D-Link DSL-2640U. Народ, помогите,а?

Comment: чем и как подключались к модему до установки LinuxMint 16 Petra MATE (х32)?

Answer (score 1):

Какая разница? С мопедом соединяетесь же через сеть (кабель, ну или wi-fi)!
1) Прочитать инструкцию к мопеду (особенно посмотреть включен ли DHCP по умолчанию и как сбрасывать настройки на заводские), сбросить до заводских настроек;
2) Mint использует ПО NetworkManager для управления подключениями? Если да, то залезть в настройки кабельного соединения и выставить получение сетевого адреса от DHCP;
3) подключиться к мопеду кабелем - Mint должен получить настройки сети от DHCP-сервера на мопеде. Все - Ваша внутренняя (домашняя) сеть настроена;
4) теперь занимаемся внешней сетью (настройка подключения к инету) на мопеде. Он должен работать в режиме роутера (маршрутизатора). Переходим на вкладку WAN и читаем как настраивать мопед в мануале + параметры выданные провайдером. Примеры есть и в сети (видимо, у вас поисковик сломался): [ВОТ](http://samnastroyu.ru/d-link/nastroika-iptv-i-interneta-na-dsl-2640u.php) или [ТУТ](http://tvoirouter.ru/nastrojjka-routera/router-d-link-dsl-2640uk-nastrojjka.html)

Comment: у него же нет интернета как он поисковиком воспользуется =) вообще удивляюсь как этот пост тут появился